# How Do I Align Right This Text?

Tags: css, text-alignment

Can you help me align some text to the right?

The page is here:

http://www.marinhomephotography.com/

I want to align the text in the black navigation menu (Home Gallery Pricing Contact )to the right, but I have not been able to do it using either float right in the div nor text-align; right for the class.

Plus, I'm an idiot. Did I mention that???

Every time I try float: right, either the black navigation bar shrinks, or it disappears.I want it to stay full page width though.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-custom1" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary"><li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-20"><a href="http://www.marinhomephotography.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://www.marinhomephotography.com/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://www.marinhomephotography.com/pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://www.marinhomephotography.com/contact/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-primary, .menu-secondary, #header .menu {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

.menu-primary li, .menu-secondary li, #header .menu li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: right;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please post the code in your question. By only linking to your site, once the problem is resolved this question loses all value.

Comment: Edited question for the user, queued for moderator review.

Answer (score 2):

Add float:right property to following classes:

```
    .menu-primary li, .menu-secondary li, #header .menu li {
float: right;
}
```

Here, screenshot of the same - http://prntscr.com/2rxrf1

Comment: heh, it's one of those times when I know it's sarcasm, but hey, I was on a break and thought of helping someone :D